# Permission issue on bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep getting this error when I load data to powerbi

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (131) Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery Storage API. Check your account permissions.. '.

So far, I have checked online but there's no direct result on how to resolve this error

Comment: Is it possible that you created a service account to connect with, and then forgot to give that service account permissions to access not only bigquery but also the storage buckets where your external table's data is stored?   Does that make sense?